# Ввод вывод математических формул (Winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms

Необходимо написать программу-тест по математике . Но хотелось бы чтобы формулы (lim, дроби, интегралы) отображались не в строчку типа x^2  а как в Word при написании формул.  Есть ли такой инструмент?

Comment: Если это тест и формулы нередактируемые, то я бы просто картинками формулы вставил. А так поглядите в сторону [MathML и чем его рендерить](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9071856/312041)

Comment: Для WPF есть [wpf-math](https://github.com/ForNeVeR/wpf-math)